# Writing to thermal sensor Mac OSX

Tags: python, c, macos, sensors

I just bought an Apple Macbook Pro 13 Mid 2010. After fixing some issues with it, I was able to boot it. Now, however, the fan after a few seconds is ramping up full speed and does not go back to normal. I already probably found a hardware fix, but since I don't have the tools currently to properly troubleshoot the problem, I thought this might be also be an opportunity to find a temporary software fix. This could also benefit people who don't dare taking a soldering iron in hand and fixing the issue properly.

So what I found out, using HWSensors/HWMonitor so far is that the laptop after a certain time get's a false reading from "Heatpipe Outgoing Air" Sensor. This reading, once the fan kicks in is constantly at 128 (°C). For a small amount of time (often just a few seconds), the reading seems correct (~30°C) and then it just shoots straight to 128.

As far as I could figure from videos like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5-Y7qNqrLw
or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3w4j_-JWrZs
The hardware fix would be relatively simple.

The question to me really just is, can I also solve this in software?

So the basic idea is to read the temp values from the sensors and as soon as the chosen one hits 128 or higher, just set it to a value of 30.

The issue is not really the high fan speed either, that can also be controlled via a fan speed control app, but rather that the CPU throttles hard, as it thinks that significant overheating is going on.

So since some apps can already read from the sensors, the real question is, can we also write to them? Or at least the memory, where the reading resides. Since I'm really not good in C, but just a Python coder, I could really use the help of someone a bit knowledgable.

So if you happen to know, where to start looking, or if there already is code floating around that I was unable to find, please help me out here.

Pseudocode:
  def tempreader():
      for sensor in list_of_sensors:
          return sensor.temperature

def evaluate_temp(sensor_temperatur):
      IF reading[tempsensorX] >= 128:
          set reading[tempsensorX] = 30
      ELSE:
          tempreader()

EDIT:
Additional info:
After I "worked" on the machine a little bit, I found a forum post:
https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/49999/Mac+running+slow+and+fan+running+at+high+speed+after+water+spill

Unplugging the connector to the airport card actually seems to help. No more high fanspeed. Also the reading of the sensor seems to be correct now. It is still present, just not false anymore, which I find highly curious.

But of course there is the problem that WIFI doesn't work with the cable detached.

So the new question is more or less, does anyone where this sensor resides and how to talk to it?

One more thing, AHT in the meantime provided me with an error code:

4SNS/1/C0000008:TND1--124
Deciphering it seems to hint toward Sensor - Temperature - Northbridge

Comment: Just a side note, I would not recommend overwriting the meaning of 128 but rather statistically speaking remove spikes such as 128 from the data's significance.

Comment: Since they are not just spikes, but a constant value, I think this does not quite work out. I assume you refer to the point of setting it to 30, if the value is 128. If it were just a spike, that would temporarily ramp up the fan, this would probably a good idea, but since it is constant, I don't think the exclusion of spikes would do much.

Comment: I was referring to how you treat the data. As you clearly wan't to write some sort of wrapper/driver; To correct the original digital data source and forward it or treat it correctly. And as I assume your proposed solution is based on a single problematic mapping which you want to correct, so in your case that would be (30, 128). However from a statistical standpoint you could also say that a value is out of order and therefore treat it as an error which may grow in significance over time. This way if your assessment is incorrect you would still be able to solve for the domain.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly, you mean that I should evaluate how long the 128 is present, compared to other values. And in case it just spikes for a second, the program does not start overwriting immediatelly? I guess the data is correct, it is just a hardware defect that provides a high value incorrectly.